# Check if elements from array are in a string

Tags: python

I want to check if there is one of my elements in my array in an string
Like: `['12', '13', '14']` is my array and my string is `'123456789'` and if one of my Array elements is in my string then it should be `True`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `any(i in s for i in lst)`? where `s` is the string and `lst` is the list of strings.

Comment: Do you want to check if a string of your list if a substring of the given string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chester's comment have it all.

But if you'd like a more readable version, something like that might help :

```
def include(lst = ['12','13','14'], search_string = '123456789'):
  for e in lst:
    if e in search_string:
      print(f'found {e}')
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

here is simple solution using `in` operator.
Steps -

1. Iterating over each element of an array.
2. Checking whether element is present or Not.
3. If present the print True and break.

```
l = ['12','13','14']
s = '123456789'

for i in l:
    if i in s:
        print(True)
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a line, you can get a mask array of your array:

```
l = ['12','13','14']
s = '123456789'
print([(X in s) for X in l])
```

This prints:

```
[True, False, False]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array = ['12', '13', '14']
string = '12345678'
for item in array:
    print(item in string)
```

You can use the "in" operator